# cakephp4 mysql error while baking template

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I would like to setup the latest CakePHP4 without persistance layer.

While trying to generate template via:

```
> cake bake template admin
```

I got following error:

connection to Mysql could not be established.....

Why do CakePHP needs Mysql connection for this task and how to get rid of this error?

Is there any possibility to disable the default mysql driver for the entire project?

Comment: With no datasource, and therefore no schema information, Bake cannot determine columns, primary keys, etc. What kind of template output would you expect when there is no datasource that Bake could introspect?

Comment: I was rather expecting an blank template.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how popular such a use case would be, you may want to suggest it over at **https://github.com/cakephp/bake**, but I don't think support for that would be added anytime soon (if at all).

Comment: If you explain the underlying problem of no connection being present, maybe someone can suggest a fix at a "higher" level, as there's pretty much no way around having a connection unless you use a custom bake command and custom bake templates.

Comment: @ndm, You are right, this approach will be definitely not really an popular one, since getting rid of any persistance layer. I wasn't aware that the bake command works only with an underlying database connection. So I have no choice as to create them manually.